# Alternative libraries to SendKeys.Send?

Tags: vb.net

A relatively simple question, does anyone know any good 3rd party libraries for sending keys. I am specifically looking for Visual Basic libraries.

Comment: Use the Windows Message API to send key press messages directly to window handles.

Comment: Waht should the alternative provide over the original?

Comment: I find the original libraries to be unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [`Windows Input Simulator`](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).

From the site(converted to VB):

```
Public Sub SayHello()
   InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("Say hello!")
End Sub

Public Sub ShoutHello()
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_H);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_L);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_L);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_O);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_1);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
End Sub
```